# Generate AWS Signed Requests in Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, amazon-web-services, api

From my Angular 8 app, I want to call a REST endpoint which is hosted on AWS API Gateway. The authorization of the endpoint is AWS_IAM, meaning that the request needs to be signed.

How can signed request be done in Angular? There is a popular package aws4 (https://www.npmjs.com/package/aws4) for JavaScript which would be my preferred option. However, I am not able to use this JS Package in my Angular app. This is what I did:

1. `npm install aws4` in angular project folder
2. `import * as aws4 from '../../../node_modules/aws4/aws4.js';` in my api.service.ts (which is the angular service for calling the APIs).

When using the sign method from my API service

```
const signedRequest = aws4.sign(opts, {
accessKeyId: accessKey,
secretAccessKey: secretKey,
sessionToken: session})
```

I am getting following error:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: Buffer is not defined at
>   Object../node_modules/core-util-is/lib/util.js at _webpack_require_

I have also tried to use declare `declare var aws4: any`in my API service instead of importing, however I am always getting the error above.

How can the package aws4 be imported to Angular 8 or alternatively, how can signed requests be generated for AWS in an Angular 8 app without implementing each step (meaning I want to use a library).

Update:
After adding Buffer, I am getting following error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'slice' of undefined
>       at Object../node_modules/readable-stream/lib/_stream_writable.js (_stream_writable.js:57)
>       at **webpack_require** (bootstrap:79)
>       at Object../node_modules/readable-stream/readable-browser.js (readable-browser.js:4)
>       at **webpack_require** (bootstrap:79)
>       at Object../node_modules/stream-browserify/index.js (index.js:28)
>       at **webpack_require** (bootstrap:79)
>       at Object../node_modules/hash-base/index.js (index.js:3)
>       at **webpack_require** (bootstrap:79)
>       at Object../node_modules/md5.js/index.js (index.js:3)
>       at **webpack_require** (bootstrap:79)

Comment: If you're unable to make this work with the current version of aws4 then you might consider installing an older version that doesn't rely on, and has no dependencies  that rely on, Buffer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At first, I tried to use *crypto-browserify*, but unfortunately, I got the exact same error as I got with *crypto*.
Therefore, I implemented the request signing myself using this example:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/sigv4-signed-request-examples.html

The example is for python, but can easily be adapted for Javascript/Typescript.

As described here:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/signature-v4-examples.html

I used ***crypto-js*** instead of *crypto*, and did not get any errors.

Answer (score 0):

Install the buffer package using npm or yarn `npm install buffer`. And add the following into polyfills.ts ():

```
global.Buffer = global.Buffer || require('buffer').Buffer;
```

Comment: Thank you. I added Buffer as described, but now I am getting an error Cannot read property 'slice' of undefined. Do you know how to proceed here?

Comment: Can paste some of the stack trace? I am guessing you are passing null somewhere to aws4

Comment: I updated more of stack trace in the question above

Comment: Can you also just use this for importing aws4


import * as aws4 from 'aws4';

Comment: I have updated the import accordingly, unfortunately the error did not change.

Comment: Try using this library instead https://github.com/bhanuhiteshi/ngx-aws4#readme

Comment: I would like to use aws4 because it is far more popular and active. Has anyone been able to get this library to work with Angular 8 or is there another way of creating signed requests in Angular 8 for AWS API GW?

Comment: The problem is the crypto library they use in aws4. You could fork aws4 and replace crypto with crypto-browserify. 
https://www.npmjs.com/package/crypto-browserify